# When I compile a file in IntelliJ on a maven project, what does it run?

Tags: scala, vim, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make the move to VIM for my Java/Scala work. However it seems I cannot compile a single file using Maven. When developing I typically like to compile a file just to make sure it compiles before I compile the whole project.

In intellij I can choose to compile a single file that I'm on, what does that run behind the scenes so that my classpath is loaded with all my dependencies from maven?

The question boils down to what can I run from the command line to compile a file using Maven the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to compile from IDEA is **Build | Make**. It will compile the changed files and all the dependencies. Compiling single file is also possible, IDEA will use Java Compiler API (like javac does) for such compilation.

IDEA doesn't compile using Maven in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think single file is compiled using maven. I think IDEA just "knows" what what libraries are necessary (by parsing your pom.xml) and adds it to the classpath when running scalac.

Comment: at the end of the day it has to run some command, that's what I'm looking for.